# How to add a MenuManager to ToolBarManager in SWT?

Tags: java, menu, swt

I have a toolbar and a toolbar manager that contains some action and a **MenuActionManager**. I need to add a separator between some of these actions.MenuActionManger doesn't accept separators but MenuManager does.so I want to create a **MenuManager** and add these actions to it and then attach this MenuManager to ToolBarManager or ToolBar.
I try adding it to toolBar but it's not working.

```
ToolBar toolBar =new ToolBar(parent, SWT.None);
ToolBarManager manager= new ToolBarManager(toolBar);
manager.add(action1);
manager.add(action2);
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager("test");
menuManager.add(menuAction1);
menuManager.add(new Separator());
menuManager.add(menuAction2);
menuManager.updateAll(true);
menuManager.setVisible(true);
menuManager.fill(toolBar, -1);
manager.update(true);
```

Comment: What is `MenuManagerAction`? You can't add a menu to a tool bar, you would have to make a drop down tool bar action that shows the menu.

Comment: @greg-449 sorry MenuActionManager.I want to add a separator between actions of a MenuActionManager. is there a way or I should use menu manager instead. I try using menu manager and adding separators but when the user selects an item I want to image descriptor and tooltip of the menu modify as well to the selected item.

Comment: I don't know what MenuActionManager is either, it is not standard Eclipse.